# Error creating ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to set an adapter to a spinner but I don't know why I am getting the following error:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(com.example.app.DialogBox,int, java.util.list)'

Here is the method where I try to populate the spinner and set the adapter for it:

```
public class DialogBox extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

     // To fill the age spinner
    public ArrayAdapter<Integer> populateAgeSpinner () {

        Log.d(TAG ,"populateAgeSpinner - Ini");

        List age =  new ArrayList<String>();
        age.add("");

        for(int i =  18; i <= 100; i++) {
            age.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> spinnerAgeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,R.layout.spinner_item_layout, age);
        spinnerAgeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Log.d(TAG ,"populateAgeSpinner - Fi");

        return spinnerAgeAdapter;

    }
}
```

And this is the `spinner_item_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_text"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:background="@color/com_facebook_button_send_background_color"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) does not extend [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) needed for each of [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) constructors. You should use `Context` or any of its inheritors in the constructor. To get `Context` call the [`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) method of `Fragment`.